# How many namespace are there in salesforce

Tags: namespaces, salesforce, apex

I know some name of salesforce provided namespace like System, Database, ApexClass, Messaging.

Can anybody give me the list of all Namespace in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list of them in the Apex [Developers Guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_namespace_System.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_namespace_System.htm|SkinName=webhelp).

- ApexPages Namespace
- Approval Namespace
- Auth Namespace
- Canvas Namespace
- ChatterAnswers Namespace
- ConnectApi Namespace
- Database Namespace
- Dom Namespace
- Flow Namespace
- KbManagement Namespace
- Messaging Namespace
- Process Namespace
- QuickAction Namespace
- Reports Namespace
- Schema Namespace
- Site Namespace
- Support Namespace
- System Namespace